# two dimensional array of FILE pointers with malloc

Tags: c++

Im trying to crate a two dimensional array of FILE pointer

when I did this:

```
FILE *pFile = OpenFile(fileName);
FILE **lossArr  =   (FILE**)malloc(sizeof(FILE*) * i * j);

lossArr [0] =  pFile;
fputs ("some text\n",(lossArr[0]));
```

it worked fine,

but when I added `*` to make it two dimensional array:

```
FILE *pFile = OpenFile(fileName);
FILE ***lossArr =   (FILE**)malloc(sizeof(FILE*) * i * j);

lossArr[0][0] =  pFile;
fputs ("some text\n",(lossArr[0][0]));
```

I got `Access violation writing location 0xcdcdcdcd.`

I saw declaration of two dimensional array with malloc, but I would like to know what is the way to create two dimensional array of FILE pointers? what is wrong with my code.

thanks in advanced!

Comment: To assist you writing code you could do `typedef FILE *FILEPOINTER;` and then use a standard recipe for allocating a 2D array of FILEPOINTER (there are hundreds of threads of that on SO).   Normally I would not recommend pointer typedefs , but since `FILE *` is opaque , this situation is an exception.

Comment: You should decide which language you're using. If it's C++, then use the C++ library (streams, `vector`, etc.) and save yourself the pain (and long debugging sessions) of manual memory wrangling. If it's C, then use a C compiler so you don't need those horrible casts. This code is the worst of both languages, and will give you nightmares if you continue like this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First. You should allocate memory for each raw in array

```
int ii;
typedef FILE * FILE_PTR;
FILE_PTR ** lossArr = (FILE_PTR**)malloc( sizeof( FILE_PTR* ) * i );
for ( ii = 0; ii < i; ii++ ) {
    lossArr[ ii ] = (FILE_PTR*)malloc( sizeof( FILE_PTR ) * j );
}
// now you can use lossArr[ x ][ y ], where x = 0..i-1, y = 0..j-1
```

Second. This is C, but not C++. If you can use C++, then use [std::vector](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector)

Comment: In C, [don't cast malloc](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc) ! Other than that, great answer

Answer (score 0):

Your approach is similar to that presented [here](http://www.eskimo.com/~scs/cclass/int/sx9b.html), which uses an array of pointer-to-pointers, and your code is crashing as you haven't allocated the second dimension of pointers.

You could continue your approach by calculating the index into `lossArr` yourself,  treating a single-dimension array as two-dimensional using a macro:

```
#define INDEX_FOR(r, c) r * i + c

FILE** lossArr = (FILE**)malloc(sizeof(FILE*) * i * j);
lossArr[INDEX_FOR(0, 0)] = pFile;
```

However using `std::array` is better including using `fstream` instead of `FILE*`:

```
std::array<std::array<std::fstream, j>, i> lossArr;
lossArr[0][0] =  file;
```

Comment: Your malloc is wrong , the `sizeof` expression must refer to the size of the thing being pointed to, not the size of the pointer

Comment: @MattMcNabb Not true; the OP wants an array of `FILE*` not `FILE`.

Comment: My statement is true in all situations. If you are allocating for a `T *` then you must use `sizeof(T)` or equivalent as the size of each element. If `T` is `FILE*` then you must use a `FILE **` to point to what you've allocated.

Comment: @MattMcNabb Nope again; my first example creates an artificial two-dimensional array from a single-dimension array (hence the use of the macro).

Comment: Your code doesn't even compile, `lossArr[x]` has type `FILE` and `pFile` has type `FILE *`.

Comment: @MattMcNabb What are you talking about?

Comment: You are mallocing the wrong amount of memory, and your code doesn't compile.

Comment: `malloc(sizeof(FILE*) * i * j)`: this should be kept as `FILE**`

Comment: Yep; fixed.  Bottom line, though, is use `std::array`.

Answer (score 0):

Please look at this in reference to your problem:

```
int a[5] = {1,2,3,4,5};
a[1] = a[4];
```

is equal to

```
int b[5] = {1,2,3,4,5};
int *a = b;
a[1] = a[4];
```

but

```
int a[2][2] = { {1,2}, {3,4} };
a[0][0] = a[1][1];
```

is not equal to

```
int b[2][2] = { {1,2}, {3,4} };
int **a = b;  // compilation error
a[0][0] = a[1][1]; // runtime error
```

but

```
int b[2][2] = { {1,2}, {3,4} };
int *a = b;
a[0] = a[3];
```

will work

Pointers can't point to multidimensional arrays insted they point to arryas of pointers. If you point a pointer to multidimensional array it will flatten an array.

```
int **a;
```

mean pointer to int pointer not pointer to 2d int array

Answer (score 0):

Doing this:

```
FILE **lossArr  =   (FILE**)malloc(sizeof(FILE*) * i * j);
```

Only gets you a pointer to a space of `i*j FILE` pointers.

This:

```
FILE ***lossArr =   (FILE**)malloc(sizeof(FILE*) * i * j);
```

is even worse - you convert a `FILE**` to a `FILE***`.

Do this instead:

```
int k;
FILE ***lossArr  =   (FILE***)malloc(sizeof(FILE**) * i);
for (k = 0; k < i; k++) {
    lossArr[i] = (FILE**)malloc(sizeof(FILE*) * j);
}
```

Note: don't forget to `free` memory afterwards

```
for (k = 0; k < i; k++) {
    free(lossArr[i]);
}
free(lossArr);
```

Note2: If in `C++` as the tag suggests, you may consider using `std::vector` to avoid all this pointer wizardry

Comment: You're not allowed to malloc your own `FILE` structures, you can only use pointers returned by functions that return a `FILE*`. The type must be treated as opaque and non-movable.

Answer (score 0):

`FILE*** lossArr` is an array of array of file pointers. To initialize it, you first have to allocate an array of array pointers as in

```
lossArr = (FILE***) malloc( sizeof(FILE**) * i);
```

Then, you have to initialize each second-level array

```
for (int ii = 0; ii < i; ii++) lossArr[ii] = (FILE**) malloc( sizeof(FILE*) * j);
```

Only now is `lossArr` ready to be used.

My tip: Use 1D arrays and index them with `i*ii + jj`. They are easier to initialize and destroy, and more efficient!